# Why i can't see the button in my windows phone 7 App?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

like in title:)

I wrote from tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wp7trainingcourse_yourfirstwp7applab_topic3
does everything like there.
my code:

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="120"/> <!-- Problem resolved -->
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <!-- this i can not see any ideas what is wrong? -->

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Button x:Name = "SolveButton" Content="Solve" Margin="10"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="SolveButton_Click" />
        <StackPanel x:Name="StatusPanel" Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Your Moves: " TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Foreground="#FFD0D0D0" FontSize="17.333"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TotalMovesTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="N"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FFFFB000" FontSize="17.333"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <!-- Here i can see anything under this comment -->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1">
        <Border x:Name="CongratsBorder" Height="30" Background="#FFF10DA2" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Width="443" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                UseLayoutRounding="False" Opacity="0">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform />
                    <SkewTransform />
                    <RotateTransform />
                    <TranslateTransform />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="CONGRATULATIONS!" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Foreground="White" FontSize="17.333" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="3" Background="#FF262626" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="1" 
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform />
                    <SkewTransform />
                    <RotateTransform />
                    <TranslateTransform />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0" >
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF10DA2" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEE7923" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <Canvas Height="435" Width="435">
                <Image x:Name="PreviewImage" Height="435" Width="435" Opacity="0.2" />
                <Canvas x:Name="GameContainer" Height="435" Width="435" />
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TapToContinueTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   Text="Tap the picture to start the puzzle"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FFD0D0D0" FontSize="17.333" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" 
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" 
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"></Grid>
</Grid>

<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a Grid

And you've got multiple things in the first row of that Grid - so they are being drawn on top of each other.

- Try putting things into different Grid Rows
- Or Try replacing your outermost Grid by a StackPanel instead?

---

Also `<RowDefinition Height="0.2"/>` seems quite small for a height - try using `Height="Auto"`

Answer (score 3):

Your first stackpanel doesn't have a Grid.Row setting.  It's probably behind the TitlePanel in Row 0.

Comment: ok but when i delete TitlePanel and ContentPanel it's no diffrence

Comment: The row might not be big enough to show the button.  You're still going to end up making it play nice with the contents of that row if your intention is to put it in that row.